# Python - Resolve response Remote URL link with actual page

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get the actual page URL using the remote URL from JSON response.
Below is the remote URL I get in an JSON API response.

```
https://somesite.com/mainlink/1eb-68a8-40be-a3-5679e/utilities/927-40-b958-3b5?pagePath=teststaff
```

when I click the link, it resolves to actual page when opened in browser which in this case is

```
https://somesite.com/mainlink/recruitement/utilities/salesteam?pagePath=teststaff
```

How can programatically get this resolved URL without opening in browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`requests.head`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.head) with `allow_redirects=True` to ask for the final *URL* :

```
import requests
​
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
​
infos = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
​
```

Output :
​

```
print(infos.url)
​#https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```